# Partially Transparent Panels in WinForms app showing up black on Windows XP

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, c#-4.0

Preface: 
Pardon for the partial images - This has to do with a work-in progress for my company.

I have tested this on several fully updated Windows XP SP3 laptops using both .NET4.0 and .NET3.5.  The end result is the same.

I have a WinForms application.  On the first screen of the application I have several panels that are a partially transparent black.  I set this color by manually typing it into the properties editor.

[image]

The resulting designer code if it helps is

```
this.pnlMain.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(125)))), ((int)(((byte)(0)))), ((int)(((byte)(0)))), ((int)(((byte)(0)))));
```

The visual end result is (corner of my main panel, the main form has an image background):

[image]

When I open my application on the problematic Windows XP machines, this is the result (the panel is solid black, sorry for the camera phone):

[image]

The application looks as expected on Windows Vista -> Windows 8.

The curious thing is that on Windows XP if I click and drag the application to where it is almost completely off-screen and then drag it back into visual range, the partial transparency renders properly.

I believe there is some weird paint/invalidation issue happening.  Does anyone have any ideas?  I have looked at many of the "transparency turns black" issues on StackOverflow and most mention custom controls, however it doesn't feel like that is a solution for my problem.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: winforms doesn't (seriously) support transpacency. Your options are: 1 - use winforms as-is, not trying to get anything "cool" out of it. 2 - use WPF.

Comment: Does it only work when you move the window off screen or if you just move the window? Maybe try calling yourpanel.Invalidate() or yourpanel.Refresh() in Form.Shown. Try the same for the container of the bg image also.

Comment: There's no conceivable reason why this would not work properly, Panel supports partial transparency just fine.  Whatever might be wrong cannot possibly be guessed at from screenshots.

Comment: @HansPassant I know!  The only thing I can think of is that the hardware this is happening on is decently old.  I am going to test XP on some much newer hardware next week.

Comment: @FedericoBerasategui, Winforms supported transparency since windows 98 (proof: look at winamp) it might not possible by setting a flag but it was possible